# DispatcherTimer.Tick is not supported in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

How should I resolve the issue?

The suggested alternatives do not work either.

Error   CS1545  Property, indexer, or event 'DispatcherTimer.Tick' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'DispatcherTimer.add_Tick(EventHandler)' or 'DispatcherTimer.remove_Tick(EventRegistrationToken)'

```
_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
_timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
_timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: We can't see Timer_Tick, it is probably not a proper method.

Comment: I think it is for WPF

Comment: I don't think Xamarin Forms supports WPF's DispatcherTimer control. Here is how to create a timer in Xamarin Forms: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37203371/87698

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested Device.StartTimer class is not recognized by IntelliSense.

Comment: use System.Timers

Comment: Per this [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447523/199364), the built-in .net Timer in System.Timers works well. But I'll also comment that Device.StartTimer is in `namespace Xamarin.Forms`. After you typed `Device.`, if you wait, Intellisense should put red underline, and give you lightbulb (or maybe a drop-down) with choices `using Xamarin.Forms;` or to fully specify as `Xamarin.Forms.Device`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Windows.UI.Xaml` [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-22000) is only apply to WinRT, and `System.Windows.Threading` [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is only apply to .NET Framework. So  we can't use both of them into forms. For using timer in Xamarin forms please use [`Device.StartTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms) to replace.

```
Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, 60), () =>
{
    // do something every 60 seconds
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => 
    {
      // interact with UI elements
    });
    return true; // runs again, or false to stop
});
```

Comment: Okay, but I'd like to interact with the UI every 600  miliseconds, not every 60 seconds. And it does not offer me the opportunity to write 0.6 seconds directly as value of third parameter.

Comment: `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 600)` or `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600)` use this to replace above timespan.

Comment: I've just inserted the Device.StartTimer code snippet in the App() constructor located inside App.xaml.cs  .I've also created a private bool variable _shouldTimerRun inside App class and I've replaced return true;  with return _shouldTimerRun; There's an event available to start or stop the timer by setting the bool variable value. Is there anything else I should do in order to make the timer fully functionable?

Comment: use  private bool variable _shouldTimerRun to stop timer is recommend way.  StartTimer  has not provided other entry to manage timer.

Comment: I've just marked the answer as accepted. Thank you very much for your feedback! :)